# Link syntax doesn't link if it contains a backslash

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

This should link: [%V](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V),
as [should this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V).

Source of the above:

```
This should link: [%V](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%V),
as [should this][test].
```

Removing the backslash makes it work: [%V](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%V); but the backslash is required for this URL to work as intended.

In comments, the URL gets transformed to:

```
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V
```

Which also breaks this URL.

I'm not sure what the "best" behaviour is (are backslashes allowed in URL's?), but not linking at all seems incorrect in any case.

Comment: Comments test: [%V](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Historically](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.3) the backslash was regarded as an "unwise" character. that definition has been dropped in the following [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and [IRI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) RFCs, but it's certainly not part of the (i)fragment definition so it's not wrong to encode them, and FWIW chrome 39 seems to respect that on the link you've provided:

[image: link]

Comment: Thanks. So the behaviour in comments is correct; but the behaviour in the post body (not linking at all) is still a bug? Or is this also 'bydesign'? Shouldn't the \ be url encoded to %5C there as well?

Comment: If you use the (valid) encoded link (`[%V](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V)`) in the body it works. I don't think it's a bug because `http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%V` is (arguably) not a valid url, thus not recognized by the markdown parser. I do agree though, that it's a minor inconsistency vs the comments markdown.